# How do I serve pre-gzipped files with nginx so that they'll be shown as text in the browser?

Tags: nginx, gzip

I have a bunch of gzipped log files I'd like to serve with nginx. I want them to be served in such a way that they're automatically inflated by the browser. I assume that means I need nginx to send the files as .gz with a text/plain header. This can be done in apache with something like:

```
<FilesMatch *.gz>
    ForceType text/plain
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 26):

You need the [`HttpGzipStatic`](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpGzipStaticModule) module for this. Put `gzip_static on;` in your config and create your `.gz` files. You will need to keep both the zipped and the original file, you can then request, for example, `/css.css` and be served the zipped `/css.css.gz`

Comment: One minor note: it's suggested that both files' modification times (mtime) are the same.

Comment: And you can test it's working with `curl --header "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -I your_url`, and without the --header to check it still serves the uncompressed file if necessary.

Comment: Aparently this approach does NOT work with indexes like index.html.gz, if you add it to list of indexes using "index index.html.gz", it will be served as a download when you try to access the "$url/". I am still looking for a solution that would make gzipped indexes browsable too.

Comment: original file is not needed unless you use `try_files` http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2012-June/034102.html. I tried with `gunzip on` and `try_files` https://serverfault.com/questions/571733/nginx-gzip-static-why-are-the-non-compressed-files-required/965094#965094